# Posix select()/poll() and pthread IPC

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, posix

This is kind of generic question - however I met this problem several times already and I still haven't found the best possible solution.

Let's imagine you have program (e.g. HTTP application server) that is multithreaded and that communicates over sockets (TCP, Unix, ...). Main thread is using asynchronous IO and select() or poll() POSIX calls to dispatch traffic from/to sockets. There are also worker threads that process requests and provides responses. To send response back to the client, worker thread synchronises with main thread (that polls) 'somehow'. Core of the questions is 'how' - in terms of what is efficient. I can use pipe() - socket based IPC mechanism - but this seems to me as quite huge overhead. I tend to use some pthread IPC techniques like mutex, condition variables etc. … but these will not work with select() or poll().

Is there a common technique in POSIX (and surroundings) that address this conflict?
I guess on Windows there is WaitForMultipleObjects() function that allows that.

*Example program is crafted to illustrate an issue, I know that I can design master/worker pattern in a different way but this is not what I'm asking for. I have other cases where I'm in the same situation.*

Comment: Can you expand on *"these will not work with select()"* ? In what way do they not work with select and friend ?

Comment: "these will not work with select()" - you cannot "select" or "poll" on mutex in a same way (same call) as for socket, respective one thread has to choose if it will wait for mutex/condition or event on socket.

Comment: That is the wrong way to think about it; `select` shouldn't care whether you're using threads or not.

Comment: It is not about threads, it is about pthread IPC mainly - like mutex and conditional variables.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a signal to poke the worker thread, which will interrupt the `select()` call and return `EINTR`. This gets even easier to do with `pselect()`.

For this to work:

1. decide on a signal (or allocate a real-time signal)
2. attach an empty handler function to it (if the signal were ignored, the system call would be automatically restarted)
3. block the signal, at least in the worker thread.
4. use the signal mask argument in `pselect()` to unblock the signal while waiting.

Between threads, you can use `pthread_kill` to deliver the signal to the worker thread specifically. When another process should send the signal, you can either make sure the signal is blocked in all but the worker thread (so it will be delivered there), or use the signal handler to find out whether the signal was sent to the worker thread, and use `pthread_kill` to forward it explicitly (the worker thread still doesn't need to do anything in the signal handler).

Due to laziness on my part, I don't have a source code viewer online, but you can clone the [LibreVISA](http://www.librevisa.org/git/librevisa.git) git tree, and take a look at `src/messagepump.cpp`, where this method is used to poke the worker thread after another thread added a file descriptor to the watch list.

Comment: Yes, this (pthread_kill) is my current way of thinking. I will try this approach but I'm afraid a little bit of race condition - worker thread can raise signal just before poll()/select() is executed.
I'm also not sure about performace but this will likely be ok.

Comment: Thanks - `pselect()` is nice answer to that race condition worry. Cool.

Comment: I like this (especially the pselect + leaving the signal blocked).

Answer (score 3):

Simon Richthers answer is v good.
Another alternative might be to make main thread only responsible for listening for new connections and starting up a worker thread with the connection information so that the worker is responsible for all subsequent ‘transactions’ from this source.

My understanding is:

1. Main thread uses select.
2. Worker threads processes requests forwarded to it by main thread.
3. So need to synchronize between workers and main thread e.g. when
   worker finishes a transaction need to send response back to main
   thread which in turn forwards the response back to the source.

Why don't you remove the problem of having to synchronize between the worker thread and the main thread by making the worker thread responsible for all transactions from a particular connection?
Thus the main thread is only responsible for listening for new connections and starting up a worker thread with the connection information i.e. the file descriptor for the new connection.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the way to wake another thread is to use the `pthread_cond_wait` / `pthread_cond_timedwait` calls in thread A to wait, and for thread B to use `pthread_cond_broadcast` / `pthread_cond_signal` to pick it up. So, for instance if B is a producer and A is the consumer, the producer might add items to a linked list protected with a mutex. There would be an associated conditional variable such that after the addition of the item, it could wake thread B such that it went to see if any new items had arrived on the list, and if so removed them. I say 'associated' as then the same mutex can be associated with the condition variable as protects the list.

So far so good. Now you mention asynchronous I/O. What I've wanted to do several times is `select()` or `poll()` on a set of FDs *and* a set of condition variables, so the `select()`, `poll()` is interrupted when the condition variable is broadcasted to. There is no easy way of doing this directly; you cannot simply mix and match.

You thus need to do one of two things. Either:

- work around the problem (for instance, use a self-connected `pipe()` to send one byte to wake the `select()` up either instead of the condition variable, as well as the condition variable, or from some additional thread waiting on the condition variable; or
- convert to a more threaded model. IE use one thread for sending, one thread for receiving, and use a producer / consumer model, so the sender thread simply removes from a list / buffer and sends (blocking if necessary), and the received waits for I/O (blocking if necessary) and adds it to the list (this is what you put in italics at the end).

The second is a major design change for those of us brought up on asynchronous I/O, and the first is ugly. You are not the first to be dismayed by this, but I've not found an easy way around it. Re the first an inefficiency, if you only write one character to wake the select loop to the self-pipe, I don't think you are going to see too much inefficiency.

Comment: Yes, exactly - you cannot mix pthread IPC primitives and sockets when polling/selecting. You also nicely explained reasoning why I'm actually asking - I used both your proposals in the past, they are nice but … you correctly described their drawbacks.

Comment: One thing I forgot was that on linux if you are worried about the overhead of the pipe, you can use `eventfd` which is faster. Simon Richter's signal method is nice too (and about the least ugly way to do signals) - and I upvoted it - but the combination of signals and pthreads always scares me for portability reasons (particularly if you also use `fork()`).

Comment: 'eventfd()' is indeed quite usable here, however it is not POSIX but Linux extension so it is not portable to other platforms.